# Watching class method static variables in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I'm trying to watch a static variable inside a static class function in C++.   (Its made a little more complex by being a static variable in a static function in a template class, but I think the principal is the same).

Example class:

```
struct DoNothing
{
};

template<class A, uint32_t N, class CriticalSection=DoNothing>
class StaticPool : public A
{
private:
    struct PoolStorage
    {
        bool        m_bInUse[N];
        A           m_Items[N];
    };
    static PoolStorage& GetStaticStorage()
    {
        static PoolStorage stc_storage = {N};
        return stc_storage;
    };

public:
    StaticPool(){};
    virtual ~StaticPool(){};
    void *operator new(size_t size)  {
        CriticalSection critical;        
        void *ptr = nullptr;
        PoolStorage &pool = GetStaticStorage();
        for(unsigned i=0;i<N;++i)
        {
            if( !pool.m_bInUse[i])
            {
                pool.m_bInUse[i]=true;
                ptr = &pool.m_Items[i];
                break;
            }
        }
        return ptr;
    };
    void  operator delete(void*ptr)  {       
        CriticalSection critical;        
        PoolStorage &pool = GetStaticStorage();
        for(unsigned i=0;i<N;++i)
        {
            if(&pool.m_Items[i]==ptr && pool.m_bInUse[i])
            {
                pool.m_bInUse[i] = false;
                break;
            }
        }
    };
};
```

I'd like to see `StaticPool<MyObjectType,10>::GetStaticStorage()::stc_storage`

I can put the variable name in the watch window while I'm in the function, but when I exit scope the watch window can no longer show the contents.

Is there a syntax to put in the watch window to specify "This class, this function, this variable"?   I've tried searching and everything that comes up seems to be for Visual Studio or Visual Studio Community edition, and not VSCode.   None of the syntaxes that I've tried have been successful and always say "-var-create:  unable to create variable objects"

I've tried:

- `StaticPool<MyObject,10>::GetStaticStorage()::stc_storage` (I think this is GDB format)
- `{StaticPool<MyObject,10>::GetStaticStorage,,}stc_storage`

Answer (score 0):

Took me a while to find the syntax, but if you're using GDB underneath, then the right watch syntax is

`'StaticPool<MyObject,10,DoNothing>::GetStaticStorage()::stc_storage'`

I found it by doing in the debug console `-exec info variables stc_storage` to see the symbol as seen by gdb.  That returned:

`StaticPool<MyObject, 10u, DoNothing>::GetStaticStorage()::stc_storage`

Trying to print in gdb with `-exec p StaticPool<MyObject, 10u ,DoNothing>::GetStaticStorage()::stc_storage` showed symbol not found, then digging on stack exchange for this topic in gdb brought something right on target showing the need for enclosing the expression in `''`:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/39736923/550235

That worked on the debug console, then copying the expression, including the `''` into the watch entry worked a charm.